# Input to allow numbers ranging from 1-8

Tags: html

I want to make four separate places to input a number ranging from 1-8 which does not accept any letter or special characters (only need numbers).

However, when I run the code, there are no inputs.

Can someone help me get the input and only allow a number from 1-8?

```html
<body>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MhMTSEL</title>
    //inputs
    <p1>M:</p1><input1 id="alpoint" value="-" /></div><be>
    <p2>S</p2><input2 id="alpoint" value="-" /></div><be>
    <p3>El</p3><input3 id="alpoint" value="-" /></div><be>
    <p4>MT/hMT</p4><input4 id="alpoint" value="-" /></div><be>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to find a better learning resource because your HTML is thoroughly invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use only one time an id in an html page.

```
    <div>
        <label for="input1">M:</label>
        <input id="alpoint1" name="input1" value="-">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="input2">S</label>
        <input id="alpoint2" name="input2" value="-">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="input3">El</label>
        <input id="alpoint3" name="input3" value="-">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="input4">MT/hMT</label>
        <input id="alpoint4" name="input4" value="-">
    </div>
```

I should be better right now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working version of what you're trying to do. I have included comments in the HTML explaining the changes from the version in your question.

I'm not sure why you were initially setting the `value` of each `input` to a minus sign (since you specify you want numbers between 1 and 8), but this initial value gets overridden anyway when you set the input type to "number," so I went ahead and took it out.  If you actually wanted numbers between -1 and -8, you would just use the negative values in the `max` and `min` attributes instead.  Note that you would set `min=-8` and `max=-1` because negative numbers go in reverse!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- The meta stuff, and the title, go inside the <head></head> tag, not the <body></body>. -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>MhMTSEL</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- This is how you include comments in HTML. The kind that starts with 2 slashes (like this: //) can only be used within a <script></script> tag, as that's the JavaScript comment syntax. -->
        <!-- inputs -->
        
        <!-- Notice the paragraph tag <p></p> is always the same - you can't append numbers to it. If you want to differentiate your paragraphs by number, you'll have to use the id attribute for the number, as I've shown below. -->
        
        <!-- If you want to constrain your inputs to only accept numbers in a certain range, you should add type="number" as well as min and max values, as in this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number -->
        <p id="1">M:
            <input type="number" class="alpoint" min=1 max=8> <!-- As @Rob noted, you shouldn't use a slash before the closing bracket of the input tag. -->
        </p><br>
        <p id="2">S
            <input type="number" class="alpoint" min=1 max=8> <!-- Like @Lucas said, ids must be unique. If you want the same attribute to belong to a number of items, use the class attribute instead of the id. -->
        </p><br>
        <p id="3">El
            <input type="number" class="alpoint" min=1 max=8>
        </p><br> <!-- The line break tag is <br>, not <be>. <be> is not a valid HTML tag. -->
        <p id="4">MT/hMT
            <input type="number" class="alpoint" min=1 max=8>
        </p>
    </body>
       
</html>
```

If you're looking for a great tutorial on learning HTML, here is a link to the one on Khan Academy, which is where I learned: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css

I also often use w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com

and the official MDN developer documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

as references for looking up specific syntax questions (like, for example, how to specify that an input tag should only accept numbers).

I hope this helps!